# XMLHttpRequest content length mismatch but client sent 65,536 bytes

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asynchronous, fiddler

I was trying to upload file in `MVC4` using `jquery`. But I am getting this error on `Fiddler` when try to upload any file. Hence, I am receiving `Request.Files.Count = 0`.

How to increase a request buffer size?

```
function UploadFile() {        
    var formdata = new FormData(); //FormData object
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('Plans');

    for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        //Appending each file to FormData object
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
    }

    //Creating an XMLHttpRequest and sending
    var nexturl = '/Project/AjaxFileUploads';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', nexturl, true);
    xhr.send(formdata);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Error message I am receiving in fiddler :

> **#1153 Content-Length mismatch: Request Header indicated 5,530,149 bytes, but client sent 65,536 bytes.**

Answer (score 0):

The message from Fiddler indicates that the client has promised to send 5.53mb but in fact only sent 64kb before closing the connection.

In which browser are you hitting the problem? Are you doing anything that would cause a premature garbage collection of the XmlHttpRequest object (e.g. navigating to another page during the middle of the upload)?